# Mongodb document versioning using spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data in my Java application to connect to MongoDb and have a requirement around versioning the documents (basically storing the history).
It seems that its pretty straightforward in Ruby, if one uses [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#versioning)

I was wondering if spring data has something similar for Java. Or are you better of trying to implement your own.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is a very good feature in Spring data which is auditing you can refer to the following link

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/auditing-entities-in-spring-data-mongodb-2.html

Comment: Answering in links is discouraged in Stack overflow. Provide the portion of that page that answers the question of OP in your answer so that future readers may be able to read it even if the link is broken.

Answer (score -2):

After lot of research I found that https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/. This works like rock solid and very easy to implement.

This library helps to store all the history of the changed fields and easy to query over it and it has great support of it. The sample POC shared here: https://nullbeans.com/auditing-using-spring-boot-mongodb-and-javers/